# How to Resolve PyAudio Installation Error

Tags: python

** pip install PyAudio
  File "", line 1
    pip install PyAudio
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I faced a Problem like that [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EUAe.png)

**

Comment: Consider embedding the image rather than linking to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are installing inside the Python shell.You need to execute `python -m pip install pyaudio` from the command prompt instead without going into the python shell

Answer (score 0):

do not run it as a python, launch the command directly from the shell